# How can I get the last value in an node with same name in different places?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Goodmorning all,

I have a problem containing an node which recurs in different places... The cac:InvoiceLine is variabel and can be more or less than 4. What i want is that the code always gets the last 4 characters of the result/value from the LAST cac:InvoiceLine/cac:Item/cbc:Description. In this case it is 6.00 How can I do this?

This is the XML-file I got:

```
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2" udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:draft:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" stat="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:DocumentStatusCode-1.0" ccts="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CoreComponentParameters-2">
<UBLVersionID>2.1</UBLVersionID>
<CustomizationID>urn:www.cenbii.eu:transaction:biitrns010:ver2.0:extended:urn:www.peppol.eu:bis:peppol5a:ver2.0:extended:e-fff:ver3.0</CustomizationID>
<ProfileID>FFF.BE Teamleader 1.0</ProfileID>
<ID>192972</ID>
<IssueDate>2019-11-30</IssueDate>
<InvoiceTypeCode listID="UNCL1001">380</InvoiceTypeCode>
<Note>Onze referentie: 5573395</Note>
<TaxPointDate>2019-11-30</TaxPointDate>
<DocumentCurrencyCode listID="ISO4217">EUR</DocumentCurrencyCode>
<LineCountNumeric>4</LineCountNumeric>
<AdditionalDocumentReference>
<ID>78616_1575288029_TL_MXEfAC</ID>
<DocumentType>CommercialInvoice</DocumentType>
<Attachment>
<EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject> image here </EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject>
</Attachment>
</AdditionalDocumentReference>
<AdditionalDocumentReference>
<ID>eFFF</ID>
<DocumentType>Teamleader CRM 1.0</DocumentType>
</AdditionalDocumentReference>
<AccountingSupplierParty>
<Party>
<EndpointID schemeID="BE:CBE"></EndpointID>
<PartyIdentification>
<ID schemeID="BE:CBE"></ID>
</PartyIdentification>
<PartyName>
<Name>test</Name>
</PartyName>
<PostalAddress>
<StreetName>test</StreetName>
<CityName>test</CityName>
<PostalZone>4444</PostalZone>
<Country>
<IdentificationCode listID="ISO3166-1:Alpha2">BE</IdentificationCode>
</Country>
</PostalAddress>
<PartyTaxScheme>
<CompanyID schemeID="BE:VAT">blabla</CompanyID>
<TaxScheme>
<ID>VAT</ID>
</TaxScheme>
</PartyTaxScheme>
<PartyLegalEntity>
<CompanyID schemeID="BE:VAT">blabla</CompanyID>
</PartyLegalEntity>
</Party>
</AccountingSupplierParty>
<AccountingCustomerParty>
<Party>
<EndpointID schemeID="BE:CBE">blabla</EndpointID>
<PartyIdentification>
<ID schemeID="BE:CBE">blabla</ID>
</PartyIdentification>
<PartyName>
<Name>test 2</Name>
</PartyName>
<PostalAddress>
<StreetName>test2</StreetName>
<CityName>testtest</CityName>
<PostalZone>1800</PostalZone>
<Country>
<IdentificationCode listID="ISO3166-1:Alpha2">BE</IdentificationCode>
</Country>
</PostalAddress>
<PartyTaxScheme>
<CompanyID schemeID="BE:VAT">Blablabla</CompanyID>
<TaxScheme>
<ID>VAT</ID>
</TaxScheme>
</PartyTaxScheme>
<PartyLegalEntity>
<CompanyID schemeID="BE:VAT">blablabla</CompanyID>
</PartyLegalEntity>
</Party>
</AccountingCustomerParty>
<PaymentMeans>
<PaymentMeansCode listID="UNCL4461" listName="Payment Means" listURI="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/os-UBL-2.0-update/cl/gc/default/PaymentMeansCode-2.0.gc">1</PaymentMeansCode>
<PaymentDueDate>2019-12-30</PaymentDueDate>
<InstructionID>007113333029</InstructionID>
<PaymentID>007113333029</PaymentID>
<PayeeFinancialAccount>
<ID schemeID="IBAN">BE243343523452345</ID>
<FinancialInstitutionBranch>
<FinancialInstitution>
<ID schemeID="BIC">GKCCBEBB</ID>
</FinancialInstitution>
</FinancialInstitutionBranch>
</PayeeFinancialAccount>
</PaymentMeans>
<TaxTotal>
<TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">0.00</TaxAmount>
<TaxSubtotal>
<TaxableAmount currencyID="EUR">377.25</TaxableAmount>
<TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">0.00</TaxAmount>
<TaxCategory>
<ID>E</ID>
<Name>45</Name>
<Percent>0</Percent>
<TaxScheme>
<ID>VAT</ID>
</TaxScheme>
</TaxCategory>
</TaxSubtotal>
</TaxTotal>
<LegalMonetaryTotal>
<LineExtensionAmount currencyID="EUR">377.25</LineExtensionAmount>
<TaxExclusiveAmount currencyID="EUR">377.25</TaxExclusiveAmount>
<TaxInclusiveAmount currencyID="EUR">377.25</TaxInclusiveAmount>
<PayableAmount currencyID="EUR">377.25</PayableAmount>
</LegalMonetaryTotal>
<InvoiceLine>
<ID>1</ID>
<InvoicedQuantity>1.0000</InvoicedQuantity>
<LineExtensionAmount currencyID="EUR">71.50</LineExtensionAmount>
<TaxTotal>
<TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">0.00</TaxAmount>
<TaxSubtotal>
<TaxableAmount currencyID="EUR">71.50</TaxableAmount>
<TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">0.00</TaxAmount>
<TaxCategory>
<ID>E</ID>
<Name>45</Name>
<Percent>0</Percent>
<TaxScheme>
<ID>VAT</ID>
</TaxScheme>
</TaxCategory>
</TaxSubtotal>
</TaxTotal>
<Item>
<Description>Goods delivered</Description>
</Item>
<Price>
<PriceAmount currencyID="EUR">71.5000</PriceAmount>
</Price>
</InvoiceLine>
<InvoiceLine>
<ID>2</ID>
<InvoicedQuantity>1.0000</InvoicedQuantity>
<LineExtensionAmount currencyID="EUR">101.75</LineExtensionAmount>
<TaxTotal>
<TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">0.00</TaxAmount>
<TaxSubtotal>
<TaxableAmount currencyID="EUR">101.75</TaxableAmount>
<TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">0.00</TaxAmount>
<TaxCategory>
<ID>E</ID>
<Name>45</Name>
<Percent>0</Percent>
<TaxScheme>
<ID>VAT</ID>
</TaxScheme>
</TaxCategory>
</TaxSubtotal>
</TaxTotal>
<Item>
<Description>Other costs</Description>
</Item>
<Price>
<PriceAmount currencyID="EUR">101.7500</PriceAmount>
</Price>
</InvoiceLine>
<InvoiceLine>
<ID>3</ID>
<InvoicedQuantity>1.0000</InvoicedQuantity>
<LineExtensionAmount currencyID="EUR">204.00</LineExtensionAmount>
<TaxTotal>
<TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">0.00</TaxAmount>
<TaxSubtotal>
<TaxableAmount currencyID="EUR">204.00</TaxableAmount>
<TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">0.00</TaxAmount>
<TaxCategory>
<ID>E</ID>
<Name>45</Name>
<Percent>0</Percent>
<TaxScheme>
<ID>VAT</ID>
</TaxScheme>
</TaxCategory>
</TaxSubtotal>
</TaxTotal>
<Item>
<Description>BLADIEBLAD</Description>
</Item>
<Price>
<PriceAmount currencyID="EUR">204.0000</PriceAmount>
</Price>
</InvoiceLine>
<InvoiceLine>
<ID>4</ID>
<InvoicedQuantity>0.0000</InvoicedQuantity>
<LineExtensionAmount currencyID="EUR">0.00</LineExtensionAmount>
<TaxTotal>
<TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">0.00</TaxAmount>
<TaxSubtotal>
<TaxableAmount currencyID="EUR">0.00</TaxableAmount>
<TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">0.00</TaxAmount>
<TaxCategory>
<ID>E</ID>
<Name>45</Name>
<Percent>0</Percent>
<TaxScheme>
<ID>VAT</ID>
</TaxScheme>
</TaxCategory>
</TaxSubtotal>
</TaxTotal>
<Item>
<Description>123456.00</Description>
</Item>
<Price>
<PriceAmount currencyID="EUR">0.0000</PriceAmount>
</Price>
</InvoiceLine>
</Invoice>
```

I tried this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:for-each select="/x:Invoice/cac:InvoiceLine/cac:Item">
      <xsl:if test="cbc:Description"><xsl:value-of select="substring(cbc:Description, string-length(cbc:Description) - 3)" /></xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

This one gets the last 4 characters from all the values in Description which is in the different IncoiceLines/Item. I just want the LAST one. I can't connect to a unique cac:ID, because thats also variable. I always want it to get the last value in this path.. How can i Do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:x="http://www.vb.org/someNS"
  xmlns:cbc="http://www.vb.org/someNS"
  xmlns:cac="http://www.vb.org/someNS"
  version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="descendant::*:Description[not(following::*:Description)]">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(., string-length(.) - (string-length(.) - (string-length(.)-3)))"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This did it for me!! You sir are a LEGEND. Thank you. I was the whole morning busy trying to figure out what I was doing wrong. Im 10 months into xslt (im a gamer, but no backgrounds with IT or codes etc.) and trying to improve my skills and step by step (thanks to you guys) I'm learning new things.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:inv="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" 
exclude-result-prefixes="inv">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="last-desc" select="inv:Invoice/inv:InvoiceLine[last()]/inv:Item/inv:Description"/>
    <output>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($last-desc, string-length($last-desc)-3)"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that this assumes you want the description from the last item of the invoice. If not all items have descriptions, and you want the description from the last item that has one, use:

```
<xsl:variable name="last-desc" select="(inv:Invoice/inv:InvoiceLine/inv:Item/inv:Description)[last()]"/>
```

---

P.S. I don't see why you need to have 3 different prefixes. The entire XML is in a single namespace;